# PHP form auto response

Tags: php, email, forms

I am using the following php code which has been given to me, it works fine, apart from the auto response bit.  I know its not a lot of code I just don't know how to do it or why it's not working.

Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title> - Contact Us</title>

<!-- css -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/reset.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/colorbox.css" />

<!-- javascript libraries -->
<?php require_once('includes/js.php'); ?>

</head>

<body>
<?php
//FIll out the settings below before using this script
$your_email = "(email address)";
$website = "(website name)";
//BOTS TO BLOCK
$bots = "/(Indy|Blaiz|Java|libwww-perl|Python|OutfoxBot|User-Agent|PycURL|AlphaServer|T8Abot|Syntryx|WinHttp|WebBandit|nicebot)/i";
//Check if known bot is visiting
if (preg_match($bots, $_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"])) {
 exit ("Sorry bots are not allowed here!");
}

//Known Exploits

$exploits = "/(content-type|bcc:|cc:|from:|reply-to:|javascript|onclick|onload)/i";

//Spam words
$spam_words = "/(viagra|poker|blackjack|porn|sex)/i";

// BAD WORDS
$words = "/(
bitch|dick|pussy|pussies|ass|fuck|cum|cumshot|cum shot|
gangbang|gang bang|god dammit|goddammit|viagra|anus|analsex
)/i";
//BAD WORD/SPAM WORD/EXPLOIT BLOCKER
function wordBlock($word) {
  //Make variables global
 global $words;
 global $exploits;
 global $spam_words;

 if (preg_match($words, $word)) {
  $word = preg_replace($words, "#####", $word);
 }
 if(preg_match($exploits,$word)){
$word = preg_replace($exploits,"",$word);

}
if(preg_match($spam_words,$word)){
  $word = preg_replace($spam_words,"$$$$",$word);
}
 return $word;
}
//CLean data function
function dataClean($data) {
 $data = stripslashes(trim(rawurldecode(strip_tags($data))));
 return $data;
}
//CREATE MAIN VARIABLES
$name = (isset ($_POST['name'])) ? dataClean($_POST['name']) : FALSE;
$company = (isset ($_POST['company'])) ? dataClean($_POST['company']) : FALSE;
$address = (isset ($_POST['address'])) ? dataClean($_POST['address']) : FALSE;
$postcode = (isset ($_POST['postcode'])) ? dataClean($_POST['postcode']) : FALSE;
$phone = (isset ($_POST['phone'])) ? dataClean($_POST['phone']) : FALSE;
$email = (isset ($_POST['email'])) ? dataClean($_POST['email']) : FALSE;
$comment = (isset ($_POST['message'])) ? wordBlock(dataClean($_POST['message'])) : FALSE;
$submit = (isset ($_POST['send'])) ? TRUE : FALSE;
$email_check = "/^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,6}$/i";
//$ip = $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];
$errors = array();
//Check if send button was clicked
if ($submit) {
 if (!$name) {
  $errors[] = "Please enter a name!";
 }
 if ($name) {
  if (!ereg("^[A-Za-z' -]*$", $name)) {
   $errors[] = "You may not use special characters in the name field!";
  }
 }
 if (!$email) {
  $errors[] = "Please enter an email address!";
 }
 if ($email) {
  if (!preg_match($email_check, $email)) {
   $errors[] = "The E-mail you entered is invalid!";
  }
 }
 /*
 if (!$subject) {
  $errors[] = "Please enter an email subject!";
 }
*/
 if (!$comment) {
  $errors[] = "Please don't leave the message field blank!";
 }
//Check if any errors are present
 if (count($errors) > 0) {
  foreach ($errors AS $error) {
   print "&bull; $error <br />";
  }
 }
 else {
//MESSAGE TO SEND TO ADMIN
//Create main headers
  $headers = "From: " . $website . " <$your_email> \n";
  $headers .= "Reply-to:" . $email . " \n";
  $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
  $headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\n";
  $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\n";
  $message = "";
  $message .= "<h1>New E-Mail From " . $website . "</h1><br /><br />";
  $message .= "<b>Name:</b> " . $name . "<br />";
  $message .= "<b>Company:</b> " . $company . "<br />";
  $message .= "<b>Address:</b> " . $address . "<br />";
  $message .= "<b>Postcode:</b > " . $postcode . "<br />";
  $message .= "<b>Phone No:</b> " . $phone . "<br />";
  $message .= "<b>E-mail:</b> " . $email . "<br />";
  $message .= "<b>Message:</b> " . $comment . "<br />";
//E-mails subject
  $mail_subject = "Message from " . $website . "";
/*
CHECK TO BE SURE FIRST E-MAIL TO ADMIN IS A SUCCESS AND SEND EMAIL TO ADMIN
OTHERWISE DON'T SEND AUTO RESPONCE
*/
  if (mail($your_email, $mail_subject, $message, $headers)) {
//UNSET ALL VARIABLES
   unset ($name, $email, $company, $address, $postcode, $phone, $comment, $_REQUEST);
//JAVASCRIPT SUCCESS MESSAGE
   echo "
   <script type='text/javascript' language='JavaScript'>
   alert('Your message has been sent');
   </script>
   ";
//SUCCESS MESSAGE TO SHOW IF JAVASCRIPT IS DISABLED
   echo "<noscript><p>THANK YOU YOUR MESSAGE HAS BEEN SENT</p></noscript>";
/*
-----------------END MAIL BLOCK FOR SENDING TO ADMIN AND START AUTO RESPONCE SEND-----------------
*/
//AUTO RESPONCE MESSAGE
//Create main headers
   $headers = "From: " . $website . " <$your_email> \n";
   $headers .= "Reply-to:" . $your_email . " \n";
   $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
   $headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\n";
   $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\n";
   $message = "";
   $message .= "<h1>Thank You For Contacting Us </h1><br /><br />";
   $message .= "On behalf of <b>" . $website . "</b> we wanna thank you for contacting us and to let you know we will respond to your message as soon as possible thank you again.";
//E-mails subject
   $mail_subject = "Thank you for contacting " . $website . "";
//Send the email
   mail($email, $mail_subject, $message, $headers);
/*
-----------------END MAIL BLOCK FOR SENDING AUTO RESPONCE -----------------
*/
  }
  else {
   echo "
   <script type='text/javascript' language='JavaScript'>
   alert('Sorry could not send your message');
   </script>
   ";
   echo "<noscript><p style='color:red;'>SORRY COULD NOT SEND YOUR MESSAGE</p></noscript>";
  }
 }
}
?>


<div id="wrapper">
 <div id="grad_overlay">

        <!-- Header -->

      <div id="header">           
          <a href="index.php" title="Regal Balustrades"><img src="images/regal_logo.png" alt="Regal Balustrades" /></a>
          <div id="strapline">        
              <img src="images/strapline.png" alt="Architectural metalwork systems" />
          </div>
      </div>

        <!-- Navigation -->

        <div id="nav">
   <?php require_once('includes/nav.php'); ?>
        </div>

        <!-- Content -->

        <div id="content">
         <div id="details">
                <p class="getintouch env">Get In Touch</p>
                <ul class="details">
                    <li>T. (0117) 935 3888</li>
                    <li>F. (0117) 967 7333</li>
                    <li>E. <a href="mailto:sales@regalbalustrades.co.uk" title="Contact via email">sales@regalbalustrades.co.uk</a></li>
                </ul>

                <p class="whereto hse">Where To Find Us</p>
                <ul class="details">
                    <li>Regal Balustrades</li>
                    <li>Regal House, </li>
                    <li>Honey Hill Road,</li> 
                    <li>Kingswood, </li>
                    <li>Bristol  BS15 4HG</li>
                </ul>

            </div>

            <div id="contact">
                <h1>Contact us</h1>
                <p>Please use this form to request further information about Regal Balustrades and our services. To speak to a member of our staff in person, please call us on 0117 9353888</p>
                <div id="form">

<form method='POST' action='<?php echo "".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].""; ?>'>

<p class='form-element'>
    <label for='name'>Name:</label>
    <input type='text' name='name' value='<?php echo "" . $_REQUEST['name'] . "";?>' />
</p>

<p class='form-element'>
    <label for='company'>Company:</label>
    <input type='text' name='company' value='<?php echo "" . $_REQUEST['company'] . "";?>' />
</p>

<p class='form-element'>
    <label for='address'>Address:</label>
    <textarea name='address' rows='5' id='address' class='address' ><?php echo "" . $_REQUEST['address'] . "";?></textarea>
</p>

<p class='form-element'>
    <label for='postcode'>Postcode:</label>
    <input type='text' name='postcode' value='<?php echo "" . $_REQUEST['postcode'] . "";?>' />
</p>

<p class='form-element'>
    <label for='phone'>Telephone:</label>
    <input type='text' name='phone' value='<?php echo "" . $_REQUEST['phone'] . "";?>' />
</p>

<p class='form-element'>
    <label for='email'>Email:</label>
    <input type='text' name='email' value='<?php echo "" . $_REQUEST['email'] . "";?>' />
</p>

</div>

<div id='form-right'>

<p class='form-element'>
    <label for='message'>Enquiry:</label>
    <textarea name='message' class='enquiry' id='enquiry' rows='5' cols='40' ><?php echo "" . $_REQUEST['message'] . "";?></textarea>
</p>

<p class='form-element'>
<input type='submit' class='submit' name='send' value='Send message' />
</p>

</div>
<p class='nb'><em>We will respond as soon as possible.</em></p>

</form>



                </div>



            </div>


        </div>        

 </div>
</div>



<!-- Footer -->

<div id="footer-container">
 <?php require_once('includes/footer.php'); ?>
</div>

<!-- js functions -->
<script>
 $(document).ready(function() {
 $("ul#navig li:nth-child(6)").addClass("navon");
 });
</script>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What exactly is not working?  What error are you getting?

Comment: I got a kick out of the bad words regex.

Comment: Oren, Hi, im not getting an error im just not receiving the auto response when i test it.  I have been testing on a live server too.

Comment: Okay i have just been testing again with the origonal code snippet which i have been given and im getting the following error.

Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely this is a problem with your mail server. Are you sure you can send mail via the `mail()` function? To find out, just run a small script on your server containing the following code:

```
<?php
mail('your@email.com', 'Test mail', 'If you receive this message, everything works fine');
?>
```

If you don't get the test message (you must change the address in the script to your own address), there may be a problem with the mail server. You can either install a mail server or  take a look at the following question to change your code so that you can send mail via external servers: [PHP - mail() function not working on my hosting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1322434/php-mail-function-not-working-on-my-hosting)

Answer (score -1):

Try getting rid of the line breaks in `$words` like the following:

```
// BAD WORDS
$words = "/(word|word|word|";
$words .= "word|word|word)/i";
```

Or

```
// BAD WORDS
$words = "/(word|word|word|word|word|word)/i";
```

Comment: There's no \n, or \r, or \r\n, or \n\r, or whatever in there, therefore there can be no line breaks in the original version. Simply splitting a string across two assignments and building it with concatenation will NOT add line breaks, unless you add them youurself.

Comment: Aww crud... sorry about the downvote. I need to read things more carefully next time. If you could edit your answer, I'll re-up the vote.